# Table to track user logins can replace the use of captcha?

Tags: security, authentication, captcha, brute-force

In terms of prevent automated login attempts. I have a table where I log each attempt for each user, and then lock the account for 30 minutes after 5 consecutive failed attempts to login.

This is enough to avoid the use of captchas?

Or both techniques are complementary? If so, how?

If this question belongs to stack security, please migrate.

Answer (score 0):

i think you're mixing to different things.

one is prevent logging by bot. that means user have to type the password in by himself instead of creating a program that does it for him. for this you have to use some kind of captcha. it's being used for example to prevent legally logged in user from automatically downloading to many resources.

completely different thing is preventing hackers from guessing other users' passwords. locking accounts is good technique to prevent it. of course, you use captchas here. it certainly makes the attack harder. you can use it for example to turn on locked password. you can even use captcha at each log in but it will make your users furious